# cannot debug javascript from webstorm anymore

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I used to be able to debug javascript from webstorm with no problem at all. 
Thanks to the jetbrains chrome extension, it simply opened a new tab in chrome and launched my site in there with no problem whatsoever.

But recently I had to reboot my computer (with a beloved windows update) and now this is not working anymore. 
When I start the debugging from webstorm chromes opens a new tab and I see the following in the address bar and then nothing...

data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PHRpdGxlPkxvYWRpbmcgaHR0cDovL3ZtLnNob3RndW4ubG9jYWwvPC90aXRsZT4=

My site is not opened and the page remains blank in chrome.

Comment: And this is why you don't ever reboot your PC ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is a result of Chrome update: some Chrome API changes introduced in v.37 break js debugger. [WEB-12418](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12418) is fixed in [WebStorm 9 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP)